# Injecting a stub service inplaced of an autowired bean for unit testing

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, dependency-injection, autowired

Given this class:

```
 public SomeClass implements SomeInterface {

      @Autowired private RemoteService rService;

 }
```

And given this unit test:

```
 public SomeClassTest {

 ...
 SomeClass sc = (SomeClass) ctx.getbean("someService");
 ..
 }
```

I want to stub the 'rService' with some other object. I do not want to have to modify the `SomeInterface` method to expose any getters/setters since 'rService' only applies to just one implementation.

Comment: If you want to have a complete ApplicationContext in place, what you're making is not really a unit test but a integration test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides just resetting the mock/stub of `RemoteService` through the setter injection within the test:

```
someClass.setRemoteService( remoteServiceMock );
```

(if the above does not work for you for some reason...) => you can create a "test-config.xml", where the only bean you'd redefine is `remoteService` with the same (real) bean name, but with a stub implementation, so it can override the real bean:

```
<bean id="remoteService" class="org.your.package.remote.RemoteServiceStub"/>
```

where `RemoteServiceStub` would extend the `RemoteService`, so it can be autowired by type into `SomeClass`

Then in your test, inject SomeClass as you would normally do:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/path/to/test-config.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyBeanTest {

    @Autowired
    private SomeClass someClass;

    @Test
    public void someClassShouldBehave() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the setter to the implementation class (`SomeClass`), and invoke the setter manually. That's the point of dependency injection, and the advantage of having an implementation and an interface : you may add methods to the implementation which won't be available through the interface.

You shouldn't have to use a Spring context for the unit test of a class.

BTW, the `getBean` method probably returns a proxy to your class, and not a `SomeClass` instance.

```
SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
sc.setRemoteService(mockRemoteService);
// test any method of sc.
```

Comment: +1 - if you need to mess with Spring contexts, you're in Integration-land. Which is fine, @tolitius has your solution. And if adding a setter offends you, just remove the `private` keyword to make your `RemoteService` field package-visible.